# List of children for a node

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a list of the children of the node - usernames.

[image]

The aim is: [steve,...]

my current attempt:

```
const starCountRef = ref(database, 'usernames/' );
        onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
          const data = snapshot.val();
          alert(data)
        });
```

which alerts me [object object ...].

Is there a way I can get each value in a list? preferably just the name of each child, not including their children too.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

```
const databaseRef = ref(database, 'usernames/');

        get(databaseRef)
          .then((snapshot) => {
            const childrenArray = [];
            snapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
              const childData = childSnapshot.key;
              childrenArray.push(childData);
            });
            console.log(childrenArray);
            alert(childrenArray)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way but seems to work okay.